# add new value in the specific dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table and want to add new column in the table by situation

for example

I have a origin table like

```
Name   
Mike     
Tom　　　
Rose
```

======================

I want get the new table like

```
Name   Selected_1  Selected_2
Mike      1          1
Tom　　　　0          1
Rose　　　 0          0
```

When in the first game Mike was selected show we should add 1 in Mike and add 0 in the other two ones.
In the second game, Mike and Tom were selected, in this time, we should add 1 in Mike and Tom and add 0 in Rose.
Any idea to acheiv that ?

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Comment: Hello the output is above. The origin table only has Name

Comment: how do we know who was selected?

Comment: @sophocles It just a example, you can assume you already knew the result and add the result to the table

Comment: Okay thanks. Hopefully I understood you correctly and my answer is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement, I will create a very small example that perhaps can help.

```
# Create your df

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mike','Tom','Rose']})

   Name
0  Mike
1   Tom
2  Rose
```

I am assuming that your selections can be stored in a `list`, and I will use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) along with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to create your 2 columns outlined:

```
# Who was selected in game 1, who was selected in game 2
g1, g2 = ['Mike'] , ['Mike','Tom']

# Evaluate
df['Selected_1'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(g1),1,0)
df['Selected_2'] = np.where(df['Name'].isin(g2),1,0)
```

Print:

```
   Name  Selected_1  Selected_2
0  Mike           1           1
1   Tom           0           1
2  Rose           0           0
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what I want to get! Very helpful